# Не работает curl на php (win)

Tags: php

Потерял собственный php pack с настроенными всеми либами для написание скриптов (речь о win version).

В интернете есть пара пакетов, но все под х64 машину. Поделитесь пожалуйста ссылкой на работающий pack x86? Хотя бы со стандартными либами, таким как curl.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Stack Overflow — это не коллекция ссылок на дистрибутивы.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь вы можете найти самые свежие версии PHP под Windows во всех возможных вариантах со всеми необходимыми расширениями:

http://windows.php.net/download/

Answer (score -1):

[Open server](https://ospanel.io/) один из лучших. Есть все основные либы для PHP, из коробки поддержка "многосайтовости", сервера Apache, Nginx, MySQL и пр. пр.

Comment: Там что то много всего. Я так понимаю это аналог денвера. Мне бы php под win с официального сайта с заиплиминейтными либами pack. :)

Comment: К слову сказать, я пока денвером и пользуюсь. Но там слишком много зависимостей. Мне бы сборку по проще для консольного режима.

Comment: @Anonymous так и ставьте на выбор с http://windows.php.net/download/. Он идёт в стандартной сборке с курлом и пр.

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь, там надо dll копировать в system32 прописывать в ini что то и это только для curl. мне бы хотелось найти нормальный рабочий пакет не только с curl. может кто нибудь поделится.

Comment: Попробуйте [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/)

Comment: Тогда XAMPP, MAMP - это для мака